# How to export a very special list to Excel or csv

Tags: python, regex, excel, csv

I got a list that looks like this:

```
['192.168.0.1  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:42','10.60.37.2 switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:41','192.168.0.240  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:40']
```

When I export to Excel, each block is in a different line which is good but all on the same column I wanted to have address in column 1 switch column 2 etc

```
                                 Excel column 1
Excel row1: 192.168.0.1  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:42
Excel row2: 10.60.37.2   switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:41
Excel row3 :192.168.0.240  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:40
```

I wanted it like this

```
          exlcol1        exlcol2       exl.col3     exl.col4 exl.col5 exl.col6 
exlrow1: 192.168.0.1     switch1   ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff   657   dynamic    port:42
exlrow2: 10.60.37.2      switch1   ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff   657   dynamic   port:41
exlrow3 :192.168.0.240   switch1   ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff   657   dynamic   port:40
```

I've tried to export it to csv instead but it says that `wtr.writerows(row)` must be a `byte.object` like, then I tried to change my list to a string to change it to byte.object but its says my `wtr.writerows(row)` should be interable.

Here's the code I used to export to csv

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
     wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',')
     for row in data11parts1:
        wtr.writerows(row)

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         print (line)
```

My preference is to export it to Excel, but I thought this could help explain you better my issues and the type of data I have.

Just to tell you that I got my data11parts1 from this append:

```
for element in data2:
    elementstring=''.join(element)
    for element in res1:
        elementstring5=''.join(element)
        if elementstring in elementstring5:
             with open(Sw1, 'r') as f3:
              for line5 in f3:
               if elementstring in line5:
                  print('managemnet-tool' + ' - ' + Sw1.rsplit('.txt',1)[0] + ' - ' + elementstring5.rsplit('-', 1)[0] + ' - ' + line5.rsplit('\n', 1)[0])
                  data11.append(elementstring5.rsplit('-',1)[0] + '  ' + Sw1.rsplit('.txt',1)[0] + ' ' + line5.rsplit('\n', 1)[0])
                  data13.append(str(line5.rsplit('\n', 1)[0]))
                  exit
```

Comment: wtr.writerows(row)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' it gives me this error.

Comment: change to `open('test.csv', 'w')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains because you opened the file for binary writing. CSV writing is easy, split your internal strings into lists (split at spaces) and write them:

```
data = ['192.168.0.1  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:42',
        '10.60.37.2 switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:41',
        '192.168.0.240  switch1 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  657 dynamic port:40']

# split the strings into their columns
dp = [d.split() for d in data]

import csv
with open("data.txt","w", newline="") as f:    # w not wb and supply newline
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write em all
    writer.writerows(dp)

with open("data.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

File content:

```
192.168.0.1,switch1,ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff,657,dynamic,port:42
10.60.37.2,switch1,ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff,657,dynamic,port:41
192.168.0.240,switch1,ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff,657,dynamic,port:40
```

See

- [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [csv.writer()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: what should i do for it to start on line 1 instead of 0, and add some a column name for each like col 1 - Ip address and so on? Other question is that on port 40 its ok but with port 3 it went to other col so, it looks like |port:40| ; and on port 3 ; |port: |3

Comment: You add a writing a header-row before `writer.writerows(dp)`: something like  `writer.writerow(['IP','What','MAC','whatever','dny?','port'])`

Comment: Do u have any idea for this ,dynamic,port:,3  comma before 3? because its printing in other col because of it

Comment: probably a space between `'port: 3'`. Try `dp = [d.replace(": ",":").split() for d in data]` - or cleanup your inputs. Off to bed now.